# Elements move around when zooming in, or while changing the viewport size

Tags: html, css, viewport

I've looked everywhere for a solution to this problem, even looked at some similar questions posted here, so please don't mark this as a duplicate, because I still can't figure this out.

As you can see here, I’m trying to keep the image above the red container, at an exact position, but when I zoom in or change the size of the screen, the image isn’t at the place I want it to be, it moves to the left of the page. (Try zooming in on the page yourself or sliding the slide all the way to the right in editor mode, to see what I mean).

I’ve tried everything from absolute and relative positioning and making the image an inline-block and block. I don’t know what to do?
Please help me understand.
[The code is here](https://codepen.io/hiashley-the-bashful/pen/VwzzeJj?editors=1100)

```css
.container {
  background: red;
  width: 50em;
  height: 50em;
  margin: 2em auto 3em auto;
  position: relative;
}

.image {
  width: 150px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 3em 0 0 13em;
}

.header {
  font-size: 3em;
  position: absolute;
  left: 6em;
  top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<img class="image" src="https://i.imgur.com/zKdvwvz.jpg" alt="" />
<div class="container">
  <h2 class="header">Hello</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrapp your code in a wrapper and define for it `margin: 0 auto;`. Furthermore you should replace in the container-margin the `auto` with `0`:

```css
#wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container {
  ...
  margin: 2em 0 3em 0;
}
```

**Working example:**

```css
#wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.image {
  width: 150px;
  margin: 3em 0 0 13em;
}

.container {
  background: red;
  width: 50em;
  height: 50em;
  margin: 2em 0 3em 0;
  position: relative;
}

.header {
  font-size: 3em;
  position: absolute;
  left: 6em;
  top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <img class="image" src="https://i.imgur.com/zKdvwvz.jpg" alt="" />
  <div class="container">
    <h2 class="header">Hello</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

If you want the wrapper (with the container) centered you could define `display: flex` for the element arround the wrapper (maybe `main`):

**Working example:**

```css
main {
  display: flex;
}

#wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.image {
  width: 150px;
  margin: 3em 0 0 13em;
}

.container {
  background: red;
  width: 50em;
  height: 50em;
  margin: 2em 0 3em 0;
  position: relative;
}

.header {
  font-size: 3em;
  position: absolute;
  left: 6em;
  top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <img class="image" src="https://i.imgur.com/zKdvwvz.jpg" alt="" />
    <div class="container">
      <h2 class="header">Hello</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: but putting left and right margins as auto centers the image on the page. I don't want it to be in the middle but slightly left above the container.  And yes, when I do put them as auto, the image no longer moves which is what I do want, but with different measurements.

Comment: Ok, that is far simpler. Check my answer...

Comment: Okay so this works but the thing is I _do_ want the container to be on the center of the page, and only the _image_ to be not centered. If that makes sense.

Here is a picture of what I want it to look like: [image](https://i.imgur.com/cb1llKr.png)

Comment: Done - test it...

Comment: It works! Thank you so much. I'm not sure how it worked but it really did the trick haha.

Comment: If that answers your question you should mark it as accepted (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Oh sorry about that. I just did it